# AIDE C++ Undefined Reference

Tags: c++, aide

Доброго! Использую AIDE.
Пытаюсь сделать прототип метода в заголовочном файле, а исполнение в .cpp, но что-то не робит (виню во всем кривой компилятор, хотя не исключено, что кривой я :D)
Вот код:

hello.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
 #include "Hider.h"
 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
  TestClass cl;
  cout « cl.getAuthor() « endl;
 }
```

Hider.h:

```
#pragma once

 class TestClass{
  public:
  std::string getAuthor();
 };
```

Hider.cpp:

```
#include "Hider.h"

 std::string TestClass::getAuthor(){
  return "Hello from C++ File :D";
 }
```

Comment: А как насчет включения в проект (или как оно там  в AIDE именуется) *обоих* cpp-файлов? Они у вас оба включены? Ну и еще - в `hider.cpp` не включается `<string>`, так что вряд ли этот файл скомпилируется - откуда же ему знать, что это такое - `std::string`...

Comment: В том-то и суть, что, насколько я знаю, в АИДЕ нельзя руками включить файлы, все делает компилятор.

Comment: Компилятор должен сам понимать, что ему компилировать, а что нет? я с AIDE не работал, но в такие чудеса что-то не верю...

Comment: Из средств управления компиляцией - только кнопка RUN

Comment: Ошибка: undefined reference to "TestClass::getAuthor()"

Comment: Извините, читайте документацию по AIDE. Если он в принципе не умеет работать с несколькими файлами (ну не верю...) - значит, запихивайте все в один. И убедитесь, что все компилруется, что нет других ошибок. И еще - учтите, что *"виню во всем кривой компилятор"* - признак, гм... очень начинающего.

Comment: Да, я я ещё тот Джуниор. Работаю с C++ только 5 дней. Перешёл с явы

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, на что именно он ругается Undefined Reference, но предполагаю, что это на string в Hider.h. Если всё же он там ругается, то надо, например, во вторую строчку вставить`#include <string>`